# horizontal legend in terra R package

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, legend, terra

With `terra` I would like to place the legend horizontally below the map.
From `help` it seems that this can be done by either passing a character to `legend` (e.g. `legend = "bottomleft"`) or by passing a list to `plg` with arguments from the base-R legend function. However, for me none of these work. Please, see code sample below.

Thanks!

```
rm(list = ls())
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)

terra::plot(r)
terra::plot(r, legend = "bottomleft")
terra::plot(r, plg = list(horiz = TRUE))
terra::plot(r, plg = list(x = 6, y = 49.5, horiz = TRUE))
```

The resulting map is in all cases as follows:

[image]

Edit: by passing an extent to plg, that covers an area outside the plot axis limit, the legend is moved in the right place, but `horiz = TRUE` still doesn't rotate it:

```
e <- c(5.6, 6.6, 49.2, 49.3)
terra::plot(r, plg = list(ext = e, horizontal = TRUE), mar = rep(4, 4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [terra code in gitHub](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/f3ee59a0ede69c0efe0f1a70e5aee438b30f6b82/R/plot_legend.R#L265), I found the solution.
You need to pass the `loc` and `ext` arguments through the `plg` list:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(terra)
library(RColorBrewer)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)

e <- c(5.5, 7.0, 49.35, 49.38)
terra::plot(r, plg = list(ext = e, loc = "bottom"))

# Change color scale, range, ticks
terra::plot(r,
            col = brewer.pal(7, "BrBG"), range = c(150, 500),
            plg = list(ext = l_ext, loc = "bottom", title = "myvar",
                       at = c(150, 200, 250, 350, 450, 500)))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `raster` and `spplot` which gives you the option to plot the legend below the plot. You can use this code:

```
library(raster)
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)
spplot(r, scales = list(draw = TRUE), colorkey = list(space = "bottom"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @Quinten :). That's exactly the output plot I was looking for , but as I understand that `terra` is meant to replace `raster`, I was trying to avoid using both packages. Anyway, I found a solution. See my answer above.